# Inserting a blank line in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I quite often find I have a need to insert a blank line either below or above the current line when editing in vim. `o` and `O` will do this, but they subsequently switch into insert mode, which is annoying. Is there any built-in command to do this which will remain in normal mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both Tim Pope's [unimpaired plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) as well as my own [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140) provide `[<Space>` and `]<Space>` mappings to add `[count]` blank lines above / below the current line.

Basically, it boils down to this:

```
nnoremap <silent> ]<Space> :<C-u>put =repeat(nr2char(10),v:count)<Bar>execute "'[-1"<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [<Space> :<C-u>put!=repeat(nr2char(10),v:count)<Bar>execute "']+1"<CR>
```

Comment: I now use this, so I've marked this as the "correct" solution; but all the answers here are great.

Comment: Great tip, although I preferred to map  `<Space>o` and  `<Space>O` instead.

Answer (score 42):

I've been using these

```
map <Enter> o<ESC>
map <S-Enter> O<ESC>
```

in my `.vimrc` for years.

Press *Enter* to insert a blank line below current, *Shift + Enter* to insert it above.

Comment: I am marking this correct as it's the simplest solution, although all these answers are good.

Comment: So simple! This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: If you don't want the cursor to move when you hit Enter, put `k` at the end of the first map and `j` at the end of the second map.

Comment: Note that mapping Shift-Enter only works with the GUI version of vim, not the terminal version.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/vim-how-to-map-shift-enter

Answer (score 8):

Yet another way to insert lines above or below:

```
nnoremap <Enter> :call append(line('.'), '')<CR>
nnoremap <S-Enter> :call append(line('.')-1, '')<CR>
```

Note that the solution from romainl and Mr Shunz will move the cursor to the newly inserted line, whereas this and also the one from Ingo Karkat will keep the cursor at the same spot.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no built-in command for that.

These mappings do what you want:

```
nnoremap <leader>o o<Esc>
nnoremap <leader>O O<Esc>
```